# Add new object inside array of objects, inside array of objects in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Considering the below bad model, as I am totally new to this.

```
{
    "uid": "some-id",
    "database": {
        "name": "nameOfDatabase",
        "collection": [
            {
                "name": "nameOfCollection",
                "fields": {
                    "0": "field_1",
                    "1": "field_2"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "nameOfAnotherCollection",
                "fields": {
                    "0": "field_1"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have the collection name (i.e database.collection.name) and I have a few fields to add to it or delete from it (there are some already existing ones under database.collection.fields, I want to add new ones or delete exiting ones).

In short how do I update/delete "fields", when I have the database name and the collection name.

I cannot figure out how to use positional operator $ in this context.

Using mongoose update as

```
Model.update(conditions, updates, options, callback);
```

I don't know what are correct `conditions` and correct `updates` parameters.

So far I have unsuccessfully used the below for model.update

```
conditions = {
    "uid": req.body.uid,
    "database.name": "test",
    "database.collection":{ $elemMatch:{"name":req.body.collection.name}}
};
updates = {
    $set: {
        "fields": req.body.collection.fields
    }
};

---------------------------------------------------------

conditions = {
    "uid": req.body.uid,
    "database.name": "test",
    "database.collection.$.name":req.body.collection.name
};
updates = {
    $addToSet: {
        "fields": req.body.collection.fields
    }
};
```

I tried a lot more but none did work, as I am totally new.
I am getting confused between $push, $set, $addToSet, what to use what not to?, how to?

The original schema is supposed to be as show below, but running queries on it is getting harder n harder.

```
{
    "uid": "some-id",
    "database": [
        { //array of database objects
            "name": "nameOfDatabase",
            "collection": [ //array of collection objects inside respective databases
                {
                    "name": "nameOfCollection",
                    "fields": { //fields inside a this particular collection
                        "0": "field_1",
                        "1": "field_2"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```